# how are secondary indexes implemented in PlayORM and are concurrent updates supported / handled?

Tags: cassandra, playorm

There are several roll your own strategies for secondary indexes that handle concurrent updates, this for example:

http://www.slideshare.net/edanuff/indexing-in-cassandra

which uses 3 ColumnFamilies.

My question is, how is the PlayORM `@NoSqlIndexed` annotation implemented; in terms of what extra ColumnFamilies are needed / created?

Additionally, are concurrent updates supported - ie, it would not be possible with two competing updates to have the index updated from one and the table from the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do concurrent updates with no locking.

Slide 46's question of Can't I get a false positive? is the same case with PlayOrm.

The one caveat is you may need to resolve on read.  Example is thus.  Say you have Fred with an address of 123 in the database.

Now, two servers make an update to Fred

- server 1 : Fred's new address is 456 (results in deleting index 123.fred and adding 456.fred)
- server 2 : Fred's new address is 789 (results in deleting index 123.fred and adding 789.fred)

This means your index may have a duplicate of 456.fred and 789.fred.  You can then resolve this on read as the query WILL return Fred when you ask for people with address 456.  There is another ticket out for us to resolve this on reads for you ;) and eliminate the entry.

We did ask about getting a change in cassandra where we could possibly do (add column 456.fred IF column 123.fred exists or fail) but not sure if they will ever implement something like that.  That would propogate a failure back to the loser(ie. last writer gets exception).  It would be nice but I am not sure they will do a feature like this.

**BIG NOTE: Unlike CQL, the query is NOT sent to all nodes.  It only puts load on the nodes that contains the index instead of all 100 computers.  ie. it can scale better this way.**

**MORE DETAIL:** On slide 27 of that presentation your link has, it is ALMOST like that for our indexes.  The format does not contain the 1, 2, 3 though.  The index format is

```
Indexes=
    {"User_Keys_By_Last_Name":{
         {"adams","e5d…"}: null,
         {"alden","e80…"}: null,        
         {"anderson","e5f…"}: null,
         {"anderson","e71…"}: null,
         {"doe","e78…"}: null,
         {"franks","e66…"}: null,
          …:…,
       }
   }
```

This way, we can avoid the read to find out if we need to use a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the second half of the name.  Instead we use the FK which we know is unique and just have to do a write.  Cassandra is all about resolving conflicts on a read anyways which is why the repair process exists.  It is based on the fact that conflicts will happen a very low percentage of the time and just take a hit then at that low percentage.

LASTLY, you can just use the command line tool to view the index!!!!  It batches stuff in about 200 columns each streaming back so you could have 1 million entries and the command line tool will happily just keep printing them until you ctrl-c it.

later,
Dean

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I didn't realize that CQL would query all nodes, can you point me in the direction of more information about that? Also one other question, since the row key to the index is 'well known' presumably does this means if it's hit a lot, you could end up with hot-spots in the ring (depending on your replication factor)?

Comment: if you use partitioning, I believe CQL hits the one partition...without partitioning, it doesn't know(but all rows are on that one node too unlike this format).  Also, yes, in any design anyone comes up with you either have hotspots or writes become more load on the system as you have to write more.  Typically we use RF 3 so you have 3 nodes you can hit for the query and typically hit 2 of the 3 nodes for that query.  I am not sure where I read that stuff(have read tons) and am not always 100% right, so feel free to double check/correct. (not sure where I got the info though)

Answer (score 1):

As of now, only 3 tables are created for all indexes in Playorm. i.e, All the indexes are stored in StringIndice, IntegerIndice and DecimalIndice column families.

Apart from that, there is a pattern under development which will created a new table for the column if required. See the pattern details at https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/issues/44.